# REST end point to get Logic App Action Inputs/Outputs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have a need to display in a web page the logic apps run history, statuses of each runs and action, inputs/outputs of each action. I am using [LogicManagementClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic) library to query workflows, runs and actions. But I don't see any option to query the input/output of each action through this client that we see in Azure by clicking "Show Raw Inputs/Outputs". The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/) for REST API does not have it either.

However I happened to notice in network calls of Azure portal that they use a different REST API end point to query the ActionInputs and ActionOutputs. The URL is of the format

```
https://prod-26.eastus.logic.azure.com/workflows/{workflowId}/runs/{runId}/actions/{actionName}/contents/ActionInputs?api-version=2016-06-01&se=<snipped>&sv=1.0&sig=<snipped>
```

Is there any way I can use this API or is it internal to Azure Portal that we don't get access to?

**Update:**
I am adding a screenshot showing the response body of the action I am interested in and this is fetched using the ~/ActionInputs endpoint by Azure Portal shown above.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can use this API or is it internal to Azure Portal that we don't get access to?

Please have a try to use the Workflow [Run Actions API- List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowrunactions/list) to get the actions detail info.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs/{runName}/actions?api-version=2016-06-01&$top&$filter={$top&$filter}
```

[image]

Then we could get the URL format as you mentioned directly.

```
https:/xxxx.eastus.logic.azure.com/workflows/{workflowId}/runs/{runId}/actions/{actionName}/contents/ActionInputs?api-version=2016-06-01&se=<snipped>&sv=1.0&sig=<snipped>
```

It is the url of inputsLink/outputsLink for action.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see an end point for ActionInputs. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated that answer with how to get the inputs/outputs for action.

Comment: What you have included in your screenshots does not make sense. If you look closely at the URL of TriggerInputs and TriggerOutputs, they are properties of a Run not that of an Action. Remember, a workflow run can have multiple actions and each action can have its own input and output. I edited my question with more info and a screenshot showing what information I am looking to get using the API.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, for action inputs or outputs we could use [Workflow Run Actions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowrunactions/list) to get the inputlink or output link for action. I have updated the answer with new screenshots.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, please mark it will help more communities who have the same issue easily to search.

Comment: Yes. It worked. I was testing my code as I got your comment. The reason why it didn't work for me in my earlier attempt is that I initially constructed the URL by myself and it resulted in an Authentication failure asking for Shared Access Signature token. But when I used the URL in the InputsLink property that you pointed out, it worked without needing to add any authorization header. Now I understand that the URL contains the SAS token in itself. Thanks for the assistance. I will mark your answer as correct.